# SweetAlert2 execute function after timer

Tags: jquery, sweetalert, sweetalert2

What am I doing wrong here?

```
swal({
    title: "Done.",
    text: "Labels Printed.",
    timer: 1000,
    type: "success",
    showConfirmButton: false

}).then(function () {

    alert('done');

});
```

The alert is not getting fired, do I need to catch 'timer' somehow? (The alert is just an example, I am actually clearing my form here.)

Also how do I get rid of  the textLabels:1 Uncaught (in promise) timer error?

I was using `.done()`

Can someone add the tag for SweetAlert2? I don't have the reputation to do it.

Mick

What do I need to do when I don't want anything to happen after?:

```
swal({
    title: "Error.",
    text: "Authorisation Failed.",
    timer: 1000,
    type: "error",
    showConfirmButton: false
}).then(
    function() {}

 )
```

like this?:

```
}).then(
        function() {},
        function() {}
       )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATED (17.11.2017):**

Starting from [v7.0.0](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2/releases/tag/v7.0.0) SweetAlert2 works exactly like was expected by question starter :)

---

<s>SweetAlert2 uses promises. Each promise can be **resolved** or **rejected** and you handling it this way:</s>

```
swal(…).then(
  function () {
    // handle resolve (confirm button)
  }, 
  function (dismiss) {
    // handle reject, dismiss can be  'cancel', 'overlay', 'close', and 'timer'
  }
)
```

Closing a modal by timer considered as a promise rejection, so you should handle it like this:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Auto close alert!',
  text: 'I will close in 2 seconds.',
  timer: 2000
}).then(function() {
  alert('done');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome, that works. I found the example confusing and didn't realise I needed the function() {}. SweetAlert2 is great. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I helped you, thanks for using the SweetAlert2!